# I'm trying to get the title for this website using BeautifulSoup but I keep getting a TypeError, how do I fix this?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
import bs4 as BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.basketball-reference.com/friv/dailyleaders.fcgi')
soup = BeautifulSoup( page.content, 'html-parser')

print (soup.title)
```

I've done a similar code to this for class, however im trying to make a webscraper of my own to get the name of the website and the leading scorers in the NBA daily. but the first stwp I'm stuck on is getting the title of the page.

Comment: please check the answer and give it a right tick if it helps, since it will be acting as a reference for others, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to get the title of the webpage.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_req = requests.get('https://www.basketball-reference.com/friv/dailyleaders.fcgi')
soup = BeautifulSoup(url_req.content, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('title').text)
```

Apart from bs4, you can also use lxml's tree.xpath to get the title. Hope this helps. Thanks